# Como añadir una columna calculada que sea la suma de los valores de otra columna condicionada a agrupar valortes repetidos de una tercera columna

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, group-by

Dada la tabla

| nombre | importe |
| --- | --- |
| juan | 10 |
| juan | 4 |
| eva | 7 |
| eva | 5 |
| eva | 7 |
| pepe | 7 |
| pepe | 2 |
| pepe | 5 |

La idea seria crear una consulta sql que me genere la siguiente tabla:

| nombre | importe | sumas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| juan | 10 | 14 |
| juan | 4 | 14 |
| eva | 7 | 19 |
| eva | 5 | 19 |
| eva | 7 | 19 |
| pepe | 7 | 15 |
| pepe | 3 | 15 |
| pepe | 5 | 15 |

SELECT *, (SELECT *, SUM(importe) FROM tabla GROUP BY nombre ') AS sumas  FROM tabla

Pero da el error de subconsulta devuelve mas de una linea.

Gracias

Comment: La solucion era con partition over

Comment: Puedes agregar una respuesta con base en [answer], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto debería funcionar:

```sql
SELECT *, (
    SELECT SUM(importe) 
    FROM tabla t2 
    WHERE t2.nombre = t1.nombre
    GROUP BY nombre ) AS sumas 
FROM tabla t1
```